# Gerrit Changes not displaying when starting new Docker Container

Tags: git, docker, gerrit

I am running Gerrit 2.14.6 on tomcat in a docker container with an external oracle db.

I am able to push a change so that it is displayed in 'Open Changes' and I am able to see the change in the database.

I can kill tomcat, restart it, and the changes are displayed in the web UI. I can kill the container, restart it, start tomcat, and the changes are displayed in the web UI.

However, if I try to start a different container, that the push didn't go through, I am unable to see the change in web UI.

I currently have all of the Gerrit cache set to 0 except for websession cache.

The git repositories are saved on a mounted directory. Each container has access to all of the projects. On application startup, all of the projects are present in web UI.

Any ideas on what I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would expect to happen because Gerrit save the changes/commits information in two different locations: database and filesystem. If I understood you correctly you started a new container without the new change info in the filesystem, right? Although the new change info is in the database, you do not have the corresponding info in the filesystem.

Edit:

Considering that your Git repositories are saved on a mounted directory, I think your issue is related to your secondary index (Lucene?) files which are maintained at GERRIT-SITE/index directory. Are they kept when you start a different container? You can try to reindex your instance to see if the changes show up:

```
GERRIT-SITE/bin/gerrit.sh stop
java -jar GERRIT-SITE/bin/gerrit.war reindex -d GERRIT-SITE
```

Comment: Made an edit. The filesystem is saved on the physical machine in a directory that gets mounted to the container on startup. In the Gerrit web UI, the projects are visible on each start up.

Comment: Yes the issue was with the indexes. Still not sure why Gerrit wasn't reindexing on startup, but I will probably move index to a mounted directory to try to share between multiple gerrit sessions.

Thanks for the help.